# RelativeLayout: Fixing TextView to bottom of another TextView centered in screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I wnat to display the following. I want a `textview` that shows `MY NAME` to appear in the center of the screen with another `textview` that says `FAVOURITE THIS` to be below it. The 2 `textviews` are surrounded by a `relativelayout`.

I have the following two `textViews`:

```
                                   <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        tools:text="My Name"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        android:id="@+id/name"
                                        android:textSize="18sp"
                                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="@string/Favourite"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                        android:id="@+id/fav"
                                        android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>
```

This xml will display this:

[image: Display1]

Now, I want 'MY NAME' to be displayed in the middle of the square, so I just added this property to the textView with the id `name` - `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` so the xml changes to:

```
                               <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    tools:text="My Name"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    android:id="@+id/name"
                                    android:textSize="18sp"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/Favourite"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:id="@+id/fav"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>
```

The result looks like this. The MY NAME is correctly displayed in the centre of the screen but the FAVOURITE THIS is still at the top and has not moved when I really want it to display below MY NAME:

[image: Display2]

I have encountered this in the problem before but did not know how to solve it. The xml code seems logical... what am I doing wrong?

This is the full xml code:

```
          <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/transparent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    >

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            android:id="@+id/picture"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                                <com.example.simon.customshapes.ForegroundSquareImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                                    android:contentDescription="@string/group_photo"
                                    android:transitionName="@string/transition"
                                    android:clickable="true"
                                    style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@color/deep_orange_500"
                                    android:layout_height="240dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    />

                                    <ProgressBar
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:id="@+id/progressBar_Pic"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        android:visibility="visible"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        tools:text="My Name"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        android:id="@+id/name"
                                        android:textSize="18sp"
                                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="@string/Favourite"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                        android:id="@+id/fav"
                                        android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>

                                </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: can you try moving these text views to linear layout and used android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" in that linear layout

Comment: You need to give your textview for "My Name" an id with android:id="@+id/<yournamefortvhere>" and in your xml for your Favourite this you need to layout_below= id/<yournamefortvhere>

Comment: guys, it doesn't matter how many times you go +id. I have tested it multiple times in xml and it works fine all the time. I can't use linearLayout unfortunately.

Comment: Could you please add information about your relative layout, and the parent of the relative layout? Since there are issues with `wrap_content` and relativelayout alignments

Comment: done. The item is square is inside a collapsingtoolbarlayout.

Comment: @Simon yep, that `wrap_content` will probably be the problem. You should set a fixed height on the layout if that is possible

Comment: perfect. Thanks @David Medenjak, please convert your comment into an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` has problems layouting views when it is set to `wrap_content`.

You should use fixed heights or a different layout (if possible) and it will work nicely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly now.  xml code confuses me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="My Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Favourite"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I myself tested the code and its working fine as expected. You need to change the background colour to see the text anyway. Edited the answer.